# which -a bash shows same path multiple times

Tags: macos, bash, mac, zsh

When I check for bash installation I get multiple bash shown:

```
➜  ~ which -a bash
/bin/bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

Why is the same path shown twice? Is there a way to remove one of the `/bin/bash` installations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Regarding "one of the `/bin/bash` installations": there is only one `/bin/bash`. You see this path listed twice, but it doesn't mean these are two installations.

Comment: Looks like you have the /bin directory twice in your PATH. I therefore would fix the PATH. BTW, why is this tagged as bash **and** zsh?

Comment: Since this was an issue with my zshrc - I was adding something to PATH multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be due to having `/bin` listed twice in your PATH. Either ignore it, or find out why it's being stored twice. I would be looking at the user resource files, eg `~/.profile` etc.